# I am confused about the php involving reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

i'm trying to make a very basic website that includes reCAPTCHA. i've obtained my site key and secret key and followed 2 tutorials so far with no luck

the sites goal is to use a form to obtain a number from the user as input and display a string once the reCAPTCHA is successful and the submit button is pressed

here is my code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> <!-- template-->
<head>
  <title>template</title>

  <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>


</head> 

<body>

<form action="/verify.php" method="get">
  Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcKeGwUAAAAAOdDqu2CzJxZdgYUXEUEPQKZBOtn"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my php

```
<html>
<body>

The number is <?php echo $_GET["number"]; ?><br>

<?php 
  if ($_GET["number"] == 42)
  echo "42 is the right answer!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

as of now the site works fine... except i don't know how to add the reCAPTCHA code and googles documentation confused me because i know very little about php.

any code samples or links to simple documentation is greatly appreciated. this is my first post on stackoverflow... i hope i followed to rules well enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would be your verify.php

```
$post_data = http_build_query(
    array(
        'secret' => CAPTCHA_SECRET, //as provided from google
        'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $post_data
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context);
$result = json_decode($response);
if ($result->success) {
//success,
echo $_GET["firstname"]; //your input field name was 'firstname' not 'number'

}else{
echo 'we think you are a bot';
//fail

}
```

Comment: thank you for the response, i fixed the typo that you noticed and added my secret key
But... now when i run the app, i get this error:
"Notice: Undefined index: g-recaptcha-response in C:\Users\Brandon\Google Drive\Wwww\Ambiguous\verify.php on line 10"

Comment: could my problem be that i'm using localhost?

Comment: i have localhost and 127.0.0.1 as my domains for the reCAPTCHA

Comment: your form needs to use POST, not GET

Comment: i'm so grateful i love you guys haha thank you so much! 
i've wanted to setup one of these reCAPTCHA things for years now

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your HTML code to this:

```
  <form method="post" action="verify.php">
    Number:<br> 
    <input type="text" name="number"><br>
    <?php
      require_once('recaptchalib.php');
      $publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
      echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    ?>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>

  <!-- more of your HTML content -->
</body>
```

and in **verify.php** add this:

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "your_private_key";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
  // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
  die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} else {
  // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  if (isset($_POST['number']) && $_POST['number'] == '42') {
    echo "42 is the right answer!";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: OP will need `recaptchalib.php`

Comment: the tutorial i used... introduced me to the 'recaptchalib.php' file... but when i ran the code... i received errors... the main one seemed to be connected to line 124 and the segment of that line that said [error-codes] 

i'd like to use that file to help better my understanding of reCAPTCHA and php... but the tutorials on that stuff for a layman like myself seem mostly absent.